# Why can't I access a .resx file as an embedded resource?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, embedded-resource, resx

I would like to write some code which can access my RESX files as embedded resources, load them as XML documents and perform some analysis on them (e.g. checking for duplicate nodes).

Note that I'm not trying to access them as collections of resources, but as the underlying XML files.

The following code:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        returnText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

...fails (returning `null` for the `stream` variable), when precisely the same code, referencing a text file in the same directory as the `.resx` file, succeeds. So it seems that `GetManifestResourceStream()` appears to deliberately ignore `.resx` files.

Can anyone suggest why, or what I might do about it?

Comment: The default build action for .resx files is to get them compiled to a .resource file and embed them into the manifest.  So the resources are directly available in their binary form without having to get them converted from xml at runtime.  It isn't clear how you've wrangled the build system to override that behavior and why you don't like the default way.  Getting the resource name wrong is also a standard mistake, use ildasm.exe on your compiled binary to see the actual names.

Comment: I haven't wrangled the build system at all. I just assumed that I would be able to analyse the resources as XML. From your comment, it seems I can't. Thanks, Hans.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the embeddeb resx resource in a Silverlight project:

```
string resourceName = "/MyAssemby;component/MyResource.resx";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(resourceName))
{ ... }
```

but fails in other projects, like in the Test.